How do I create a simple reminder system for a calendar?
I have an design/architecture and documentation/reference question for Drupal 9.5.
Suppose I'm building a custom calendar. I have a new content type, PublicEvent, with the field_date and field_n_notifies fields.
On every cron run, I want to collect all the PublicEvent nodes where field_n_notifies is greater than 0 and send a message to the author's email with the event's title as the subject, and decrement field_n_notifies by 1.
In this way, I'd have basic email reminders on a calendar.
I've looked at Rules module, but it doesn't let me do this because a cron run has no knowledge of nodes. If this is possible with the Rules module, please describe exactly how I would select the nodes. I do not see a way to do it.
I installed the FullCalendar module. It is nice, but it seems not to have this functionality.
So, this is probably need a custom module.
Which files in the custom module would this be written in?
How do I register this as a cron task?
How do I select the relevant nodes?
How do I update the relevant nodes?
How do I send many emails?
Links to documentation on these topics would be greatly appreciated. Actual code would be even better, but I think I can drive the code, given good documentation.
If this has already been implemented, please let me know.
